# trouble with simple shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

So I am working on trying to write shell scripts in linux and I have one that goes out and grabs current stock quotes and would like to save this in a txt or json format. It seems like I can run the script in the terminal, but when I set it up on crontab, it seems to fail. Can someone shed a little light, here is what I have so far.

Cron job:

```
#!/usr/bin
* * * * * PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH &&  /home/mint/Desktop/BashScripts/Stocks/GetStocks.sh
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
* * * * * echo -e "[{'Ford':' $(curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=l1') ', 'Square':' $(curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=sq&f=l1') ' }]" > stocks.txt
```

Error:

```
/home/mint/Desktop/BashScripts/Stocks/GetStocks.sh: line 2: dead.letter: command not found
```

Comment: The first 5 fields of the crontab are the schedule of when the command should be run. Why would you copy them to the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the asterisks in front of `echo`. They don't belong in a shell script.
It's interpreting them as wildcards, and trying to execute the first matching
name, which is `dead.letter`.

Also, instead of sending output to `stocks.txt`, you should give it an
absolute path to somewhere it can write like `/home/jpavlov/stocks.txt`.
And you probably want to use `>>` so it appends instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

- **Cron job:** your code looks to be is correct.
- **Shell script:** you need to remove the (all first 5 asterisks) * * * * *
  from this Shell Script. Because  thess fields of the *crontab* are to
  schedule the command execution time . so here its creating issues.

> So your final code would be following:

***Cron job:***

```
#!/usr/bin
* * * * * PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH &&  /home/mint/Desktop/BashScripts/Stocks/GetStocks.sh
```

***Shell script:***

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "[{'Ford':' $(curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=l1') ', 'Square':' $(curl -s 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=sq&f=l1') ' }]" > stocks.txt
```